# Проблема кодировки в python server & js browser client

Tags: javascript, python, websokets

Здраствуйте. Я хочу приконектить клиент на js( в браузере ) к серверу на питоне.

Вот код:

Сервер ( python ):

```
import socket, time, re
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 55555
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    try: server.bind((host, port))
    except: print("Close port...", end= "\r"); time.sleep(0.5)
    else: break
server.listen()
print(f"Server start as {host} : {port}")
while True:
    client, address = server.accept()
    print(f"New connect {address[0]}")
    client.send('\r\n'.join(['HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols', 'Upgrade: websocket', 'Connection: Upgrade', 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: '+ str(b64encode(sha1(str(re.search(r'Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.)+=', str(client.recv(4096))).group().replace("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ", "") + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11").encode('utf-8')).digest()))[2:-1] +'\r\n\r\n']).encode('ascii')) # отправка соглашения для переключения на вебсокеты
    message = client.recv(4096)#.decode('ascii')
    print(f"{address[0]} send", message)
    
    client.close()
    print(f"{address[0]} close connect")
```

Клиент( js в браузере ):

```
<script>
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:55555");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("connect done");
  socket.send("test");
};
</script>
```

Вообщем тут ставится сервер, и когда к нему подключается клиент из браузера, соединение переключается на вебсокеты, об этом я прочитал [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket), клиент успешно соединяется с сервером(да-да, я в курсе что я использую ws, а не wss), и клиент отсылает на сервер строчку `test`. Когда клиент отсылает строчку, она приходит на сервер в другой кодировке.
Вот что в консоли сервера:

```
Server start as 127.0.0.1 : 55555
New connect 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 send b'\x81\x83(\xc5\xbe\r\x19\xf4\x88'
127.0.0.1 close connect
```

`.decode('ascii')`, `.decode()`, `.decode('latin1')` не помогает.

Я не понимаю, как мне преобразовать `b'\x81\x83(\xc5\xbe\r\x19\xf4\x88'` в `test`?

Comment: Если вы не хотите использовать готовую библиотеку для вебсокетов и решили изобрести всё сами, то в первую очередь вам нужно прочитать, как устроен протокол этого самого вебсокета https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455

Comment: В данном случае интересует раздел 5.3 (Client-to-Server Masking). Во втором байте `message[1]` выставлен старший бит, что означает использование маски, и в нём же прописана длина сообщения 3 байта (что означает, что вы нас обманули и написано здесь вовсе не test). В байтах с третьего по шестой содержится маска `mask = message[2:6]`. Остаток сообщения расшифровывается, применяя операцию xor `^` с байтами маски `message[6] ^ mask[0]`, `message[7] ^ mask[1]`, `message[8] ^ mask[2]` (четвёртый байт маски не использовался, потому что текст всего 3 байта). После расшифровки получается строка `116`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя долгое время, я нашёл ещё одно решение проблемы. Нужно добавить   `<meta charset="UTF-8">` в HTML клиента.

Пример:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple client</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
  <script>
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");
    ws.onopen = function() {
      alert("open");
      ws.send("тест");
      };
      
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
      alert("message: " + e.data);
    };
      
     ws.onclose = function() {
        alert("close");
      };
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

я решил проблему. Как оказывается я пытался с помощью websoket-ов подключиться к tpc серверу. Но websoket-ы являются протоколом tpc серверов. Теперь я использую библиотеку python-websocket-server для организации сервера.
https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server